# How can we access a property of array of objects? (Typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript

```
let array = [{id:1},{id:1},{id:1},{id:1},{id:1}];
console.log(array[0].id);
```

It is showing the id of doesn't exist.?

The answer is we need to defined array = [any];

Comment: console.log(array[0].id)?

Comment: In JAVASCRIPT it will work but TYPESCRIPT is not allowing to access.

Comment: its absolutely allowed in typescript!

Comment: you're just missing the `console.log()` -  array[0].id on it's own will not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

To access the property `id` of the `n-th` item in an array of objects you can do:

```js
a[n].id
// or
a[n]['id']
```

To check if the `n-th` item in an array is `undefined` (a.k.a. doesn't exist), before accessing the `id` property, you can use:

```js
a[n] && a[n].id
// or if you want a default value in case it doesn't exist
a[n] ? a[n].id : "not found"
```

To print values you can use `console.log`.

Please see the code snippet

```js
const array = [{id: 1}, {id: 1}, {id: 1}, {id: 1}, {id: 1}];

// Accessing element in position 0
console.log(array[0]);

// Accessing the id of the element in position 0
console.log(array[0].id)
console.log(array[0]['id'])


// Accessing the id of the element in position 0 after checking its existence
console.log(array[0] && array[0].id)

// Accessing the id of the element in position 0 after checking its existence
// and returning a default value if it is not defined
console.log(array[0] ? array[0].id : "not found")

// Same as above but with an undefined value
console.log(array[99] ? array[99].id : "not found")
```

Comment: I already tried it. 

I am getting is 

error TS2493: Tuple type '[]' of length '0' has no element at index '0'

Comment: Have you tried to declare it as `let array: Array<{ id: number }> = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]` ?

Comment: it is resolved. I have updated the question with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this example:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    console.log(array[i].id);
}
```

Comment: But Why I loop through if I only want 0 index id. ?

Answer (score 0):

your question is a little confusing!

> It is showing the id of doesn't exist.?

the array[0].id will return 1;

Comment: I am expecting same like you but unfortunately it is giving an error.

Comment: but it works fine! your code is return 1 on my console. 
if you call array[10].id it will raise error because there is not such a cell in the array

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
console.log(array[0]['id']);
```

Comment: Or share your code to see where is declaration and where you are trying to console.log it. I've tried it and in my case it is functional.

Answer (score 0):

try this and it will work

```
constructor(){
    let   array = [{id:1},{id:1},{id:1},{id:1},{id:1}];
    console.log(array[0].id )
  }
```